# Angular Schema Form Load Data from JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-schema-form

I'm an hardware engineer trying to create an in-house software tool. I thought that I would be able to do so quite easily, but there are a few too many unknowns for me to progress.

I'm trying to create an in-house software solution for managing orders. I have defined a JSON Schema that is valid.

I want to set up a webpage where I can create a new order by filling out a web form. The data should then be stored as a JSON text file. I also want to be able to load a JSON text file, pre-populate the form with the current values, make some changes, and then save the changes.

I've done similar things in php and mysql, but I want to use JSON files to be able to make changes to the software tool without having to fiddle around with a database structure. I also see it as a good learning opportunity.

I'm trying to use auto generated forms (schemaform.io), and I've gotten the following code to work:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >

  <head>    

  </head>

  <body ng-app="test" ng-controller="FormController">

    <form name="ngform"
          sf-schema="schema"
          sf-form="form"
          sf-model="model"></form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/tv4/tv4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/objectpath/lib/ObjectPath.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/angular-schema-form/dist/schema-form.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/angular-schema-form/dist/bootstrap-decorator.min.js"></script>    

<script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>    


</script>
 
<script>

/*
$.getJSON("data/order.json", function(orderTemplateJson) {
    console.log(orderTemplateJson); // this will show the info it in firebug console
 $scope.$broadcast('schemaFormRedraw')
});
*/

var app = angular.module('test',['schemaForm']);
app.controller('FormController', function($scope,$http){
   $scope.schema = {
   // A long long string of text goes here
};

  $scope.form = [
    "*",
    {
      type: "submit",
      title: "Save"
    }
  ];

  $scope.model = {};
})
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

I now want to load the JSON schema from a file. I tried to move the code into the callback of a getJSON call, but I got the following error message:

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module test due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'test' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

```js
$.getJSON("data/order.json", function(orderTemplateJson) {
    console.log(orderTemplateJson); 
  
    //Moved all the angular module code to here
});
```

I've tried various things, but the problem is likely that I don't really know what I'm doing.. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, does anyone have any pointers on how I can pre-load the form with data from a JSON-file that contains data (and fits the schema)?

Thank you..

/ Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using angular it's good to do things the angular way. So first thing is that you should use angular's $http to load file instead of jQuery's `$.getJSON`. So in your controller you can do:

```
app.controller('FormController', function($scope,$http){
   $http.get("data/order.json").then(
      function success(response) {
        // please note that as this is asynchronous, 
        // the $scope.schema will be available after response
        // has been received but this should be ok
        $scope.schema = angular.fromJson(response.data);
      },
      function error(response) { /* handle error */ });
   // do other stuff
});
```

then angular [$http API reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) will be helpful

there are other things to consider using angular however it's worth to invest some time to familiarize with *the angular way* and benefit from it relatively quickly.

Even more helpful would be to use [`$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) instead of `$http` as it is dedicated to deal with json (and REST actually).

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you very much! I'll definitely look into angular concepts, that's the direction I needed.